# How much pressure completed kubernetes jobs put on the API server?

Tags: kubernetes, resources, jobs

According to [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#clean-up-finished-jobs-automatically):

> Keeping them (completed jobs) around in the system will put pressure on the API server.

I understand that regularly going through a long list of completed jobs, only to find out that none needs to run, is a waste of CPU, as well as stopped pods are a waste of disk space, but how much of a problem is this really?

Must I clean them up ASAP because the cluster goes down otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

I think the boundary number will be floating around 150k:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/cluster-large/#support (see  total pods)

There's a boundary number in any case, so it's a good idea to add some cleaner, especially if you know what is safe to clean.